# Get custom post type fields through a repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, custom-fields, acfpro

I'm in a WP project. I created a custom post type called `Team Members`
I also created a custom field block with a field called `contact_members` which is a repeater and has two sub-fields called `location_map` and `member`. This `member` sub-field is related with the custom post type `team member`.

I have no issues with getting the `location_map`. 
The issue is that I can't get the post type fields. (coming from contact_members->member->post type

```
  <?php
    $members = get_field('contact_members');
  ?>
  @foreach($members as $member)
    <div class="member {{ $member['location_map'] }}">
      <img class="map" src="{{ get_the_post_thumbnail_url($member['member']->ID) }}">
      <h3>{{ get_the_title($member['member']->ID) }}</h3>
      <p class="position">{{ $member['member']->position }}</p>
      <p class="location">{{ $member['member']->location }}</p>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I should put [0] after $member['member'], in order to reach the array's first element and after that I can finally go after what I want from the object, so:

```
<?php $members = get_field('contact_members'); ?>
@foreach($members as $member)
    <div class="member {{ $member['location_map'] }}">
        <img class="member-image" src="{{ get_the_post_thumbnail_url($member['member'][0]->ID) }}">
        <h3 class="member-name">{{ $member['member'][0]->post_title }}</h3>
        <p class="position">{{ $member['member'][0]->position }}</p>
        <p class="location">{{ $member['member'][0]->location }}</p>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

On a first look i cant see any problems with your code. What i consider the most possible senario is ( since that i guess you are using the ACF plugin ) the $member['meber'] variable holds the (int) post_id and not the Post Object. Have you tried var_dump() ?

Cheers!

Comment: In fact I did tried var_dump. For the  $member['member'], it shows: 
array(1) { [0]=> object(WP_Post)#1304 (24) { [“ID”]=> int(325) [“post_author”]=> string(1) “ etc